# OAuth 2.0 with refresh token - can I just get new access token for each call?

Tags: web-services, oauth-2.0, refresh, access-token

I'm consuming web services protected by OAuth 2.0 . Once I obtain the original access_token and refresh_token, I have to implement the following logic:

- Determine if `access_token` is no longer valid (response 401)
- Request new `access_token` using `refresh_token`
- Repeat the original request using the new `access_token`

I expect that the app would be doing a limited number of calls per minute, fetching small pieces of data. In this scenario, **Can I simplify this logic by obtaining a new access_token for each request?**

- Request an `access_token` using `refresh_token`
- Proceed with request using new `access_token`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is technically possible but defeats the OAuth 2.0 design of splitting between an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`. I would rather have your authorization server issue access tokens that are valid for a specific period of time but one that spans a "security interval" i.e. an interval during which you're fine to have the client operate independently of checks that may implemented on the Authorization Server.

Moreover, you may get a hint about the lifetime of the token in the authorization response `expires_in` parameter. You can use that to stop using the token shortly before it expires and get a new one in the way that you propse, so without first failing.

Of course your code still needs to be able to deal with a failure but it needs to do that anyway even in the case that you describe.